# UIWebview size problem with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps, uikit, zooming

I have a Tab Bar application and in there I have a Navigation Bar going back and forth between 2 views with a back button (1st view - home, 2nd view - google map website link). On the second view, when I implemented a UIWebView and gave it a google map url of my company's location, when I ran it in iOS Simulation, it ran the google map application in the UIWebView, but the problem is that in the bottom left corner, the zoom in button is showing, but the zoom out button is hiding 2/3 if the button image, so I was wondering how can I adjust the UIWebView screen size to fit in with the UINavigationController? Hope someone can help and please let me know if you do not understand my question

*I posted a picture to show you on my iOS simulator what I'm talking about, the botton left corner is where my zoom out is not fully showing
[image: Image size problem]

Comment: Pretty sure that's just how Google's site is designed. It doesn't expect a tab bar at the bottom, it expects to run within Safari.

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the webviews frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the `MKMapView` and display the Google map directly? Showing the Google maps web site seems rather strange to me, because using the native map view is way nicer and you have more control.